# No module named 'iap_pkcs7_verifier' for iap_local_receipts python

Tags: python, python-3.x, app-store-connect

I installed `iap_local_receipts` on `python3` after solving issues with `M2crypto` and `openSSL`, just to find out that python cannot resolve the import `iap_pkcs7_verifier`:

```
.../iap_receipt_verifier.py", line 1, in <module>
    from iap_pkcs7_verifier import PKCS7Verifier
ImportError: No module named 'iap_pkcs7_verifier'
```

The repo is:

https://github.com/SilentCircle/iap-local-receipt

It has the missing source code for `iap_pkcs7_verifier`. How can I install directly from the repo?
Any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, M2Crypto doesn't support Py3 yet, which means that this library can't yet run on Py3 :/